# I keep getting this error: AttributeError ; could anyone lend a hand? I pasted the entire error below

Tags: python, attributeerror

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'count'

I keep getting the same error again. i don't know exactly what it could be, some help would be nice. I tried using google but I'm a little unclear on what to do in my instance. Any help would be much appreciated!

[python code: trying to create a true love generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdblr.jpg)

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

combined_name = name1 + name2
lower_case = combined_name.lower

t = lower_case.count("t")
r = lower_case.count("r")
u = lower_case.count("u")
e = lower_case.count("e")

true = t + r + u + e

l = lower_case.count("l")
o = lower_case.count("o")
v = lower_case.count("v")
e = lower_case.count("e")

love = l + o + v + e

love_score = str(true) + str(love)
int_score = int(love_score)

if (love_score) < 10 or (love_score > 90):
    print(
        f"Your love score is {love_score}, you go together like coke and mentos")
elif (love_score >= 40) and (love_score <= 50):
    print(f"Your score is {love_score}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {love_score} ")
```

Comment: What part of that is the [mre]?

Comment: In which line you are getting this error please tell me.

Comment: i was getting it in line 11, but it looks fine with me. i got it figured out from the people who graciously answered back.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parenthesis for `lower()`method in line 8.
Also,you need to use `int_score` variable for comparing with values since `string` can't be compared with an `integer`

Answer (score 1):

I copy/pasted your program and fixed the few errors, also mentioned by Python learner. Funny little program!

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

combined_name = name1 + name2
lower_case = combined_name.lower()

t = lower_case.count("t")
r = lower_case.count("r")
u = lower_case.count("u")
e = lower_case.count("e")

true = t + r + u + e

l = lower_case.count("l")
o = lower_case.count("o")
v = lower_case.count("v")
e = lower_case.count("e")

love = l + o + v + e

love_score = str(true) + str(love)
int_score = int(love_score)

if (int_score < 10) or (int_score > 90):
    print(f"Your love score is {str(int_score)}, you go together like coke and mentos")
elif (int_score >= 40) and (int_score <= 50):
    print(f"Your score is {str(int_score)}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {str(int_score)} ")
```

Test:

```
Welcome to the Love Calculator!
What is your name? 
Mr Beast
What is their name? 
Demi Lovato
Your score is 56
```

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error the if elif statements.
Change this

```
if (love_score) < 10 or (love_score > 90):
    print(
        f"Your love score is {love_score}, you go together like coke and mentos")
elif (love_score >= 40) and (love_score <= 50):
    print(f"Your score is {love_score}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {love_score} ")
```

To this

```
if (int_score) < 10 or (int_score > 90):
    print(
        f"Your love score is {int_score}, you go together like coke and mentos")
elif (int_score >= 40) and (int_score <= 50):
    print(f"Your score is {int_score}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {int_score} ")
```

The problem was that you have defined love_score as str and int_score as integer. In the if statements you are comparing an int with str. In if statements change 'love_score' to 'int_score'.
Hope you found it useful.